# メモ帳のサンプルにOnsenUIでタブを追加したい

Tags: javascript, monaca, onsen-ui, html5

お世話になります。

メモ帳のサンプルに、タブのサンプル機能を追加したいと思っております。

```
<ons-tabbar>
    <ons-tab icon="home" label="Home" page="StopWatch.html" active="true"></ons-tab>
    <ons-tab icon="comment" label="Comments" page="page2.html"></ons-tab>
    <ons-tab icon="gear" label="Settings" page="page3.html"></ons-tab>
</ons-tabbar>
```

上記をコピーし、該当HTMLを作成すればできるかと思ったのですができません。

初歩的な質問で大変申し訳ありませんが、回答をお願いいたします。

Comment: メモ帳のサンプルとはこれ（ http://docs.monaca.mobi/cur/ja/sampleapp/samples/memo_application/#memo-application ）のことですか？私の方で質問文を修正しましたが、違うのであれば分かりやすいように修正してください。

Comment: メモ帳のサンプルが`メモ帳アプリ`のことであれば、こちらは`jQuery Mobile`を使用します。`ons-tabbar`というのは`Onsen UI`を使用します。UIフレームワークが違いますので、タブの実現方法もそれぞれのやり方があります。ちなみに`メモ帳アプリ`には`Onsen UI`がコンポーネントとして追加されていませんが、追加したとしても上記コードをコピーしただけでは動きませんし、動くかどうかもわかりません。`jQuery Mobile`でタブを実現するか、`メモ帳アプリ`を`Onsen UI`に置き換え、タブを`ons-tabbar`で実現するかのどちらかだと思います。

Answer (score 0):

この情報だけでは推測になってしまいますが、
恐らく対象ページでOnsen UIを適用していないと思われます。

以下の様な記述は対象ページに書かれていますか？

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/onsenui.css">
```